# brickstrap's instruction on makefile

Tags: c, shell, makefile

I'm writing a `makefile` and I'm trying to compile a program write in C in a virtual shell called with this instruction:

```
shell brickstrap -p ev3dev-jessie -c ev3 shell
```

In other words, my target is to enter by a `makefile` in the brickstrap's shell and then compile a program write in C called `es1.c` with specific libraries.
The makefile's code to compile `es1.c` is this:

```
bin/es1: es1.c lib/ev3c.a
mkdir -p $(@D)
$(CC) -o $@ $< lib/ev3c.a $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude
```

How can I execute this istruction on the brickstrap's shell?

Thank you all,
Daniele

Comment: istruction? Do you mean "instruction"? So you have the makefile and want to use it? Then why don't you just run "make"?

Comment: Yes, I can run "make" but I run make on the brickstrap's shell (brickstrap is a virtual envirnment for robot EV3).  In the previous code I would open brickstrap's shell on the makefile and than compile the file. This is what I mean:
**_bin/es1: es1.c lib/ev3c.a
#OPEN THE BRICKSTRAP SHELL
mkdir -p $(@D)
$(CC) -o $@ $< lib/ev3c.a $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude_**

Comment: According to http://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/using-brickstrap-to-cross-compile/ you can start the Shell and act as if you were on the EV3. So you can call apt-get and make. You only Need to copy the makefile into the virtual Environment.

Comment: Ok this run and this is good but my project is different. I would create a file write in C on jGRASP and clicking on _make_ I would to generate the 
executable file for my Ev3. I try to install jGRASP in the brickstrap environment but it don't run.